# Как пересобрать php с --enable-shmop

Tags: php, gentoo

Стоит *gentoo* и *php 5.5*. Ставили через `emerge`.

Как пересобрать с поддержкой `--enable-shmop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [этому руководству](http://gentoo.linuxhowtos.org/TipsTricks/configoptions.htm), дополнительные опции для скрипта `configure` можно передать программе `emerge` с помощью переменной окружения `EXTRA_ECONF`.

в вашем случае команда будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$ sudo EXTRA_ECONF="--enable-shmop" emerge dev-lang/php
```

Comment: похоже на правду. пхп пересобрался, но вот приложение(phpdaemon) при запуске ругается что php не собран с shmop. как проверить?

Comment: @JamesMaynard, смотрите вывод `php -i` (примерно то же самое, что и вывод функции `phpinfo()`) — может быть, там будет что-то по этому поводу. а лучше, конечно, посмотреть лог скрипта `configure` (если он сохранился после сборки).

Comment: спасибо за вашу помощь, обнаружил что на сервере 2 версии стоит и при компиляции компилировало другую версию. это енвайрмент изменить нужно я так понимаю.

Comment: увы, `gentoo` никогда не пользовался, потому не смогу дать **правильный** *gentoo*-совет. // я бы, не мудрствуя лукаво, удалил обе версии и собрал одну с нужной опцией.

Comment: спасибо вам. разобрался, и вот эта команда которую вы мне дали именно то что мне нужно было. Спасибо. Я сам новичёк с гентой. Разобрался с версиями, нужно было сделать eselect php list cli видим список, после eselect php set cli 1 выбираем какой версией будем пользоваться.